# How do you create random nodes to appear at random times but they do not overlap current nodes in scene?

Tags: sprite-kit, swift3

I am fairly new to iOS Swift and sprite kit, but I am currently developing a game where I would like items (`SKSpriteNode`s) to appear at random times and when they do appear, they don't overlap with existing nodes in the game scene.

Below is my code so far for producing a random node and a specified with range time interval to appear across the scene width/height. However, I haven't incorporated the code that allows them to not overlap or be on top of other present nodes in the scene.

```
override func didMove(to view: SKView) {

    let wait = SKAction.wait(forDuration: 10, withRange: 5)
    let spawn = SKAction.run {
        self.randomFood()
    }

    let spawning = SKAction.sequence([wait,spawn])    
    self.run(SKAction.repeat((spawning), count: 5))
}

func randomFood() {
    //supposed to pick random point within the screen width
    let xPos = randomBetweenNumbers(firstNum: 0, secondNum: frame.width )

    let foodNode = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "burgerFood") //create a new food item each time
    foodNode.position = CGPoint(x: xPos, y: self.frame.size.height/2)
    foodNode.setScale(0.10)
    foodNode.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: foodNode.size.width/2)
    foodNode.zPosition = 10
    foodNode.alpha = 1
    foodNode.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
    foodNode.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = 0
    foodNode.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = 0
    addChild(foodNode)
}

func randomBetweenNumbers(firstNum: CGFloat, secondNum: CGFloat) -> CGFloat {
    return CGFloat(arc4random()) / CGFloat(UINT32_MAX) * abs(firstNum - secondNum) + min(firstNum, secondNum)
}
```

Comment: why do you have physics bodies on your nodes?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion but the foodNode for example is actually a SKSpriteNode I just called it foodNode for my reference and because didn't want to get confused with the image name which has the word Food in it.